# How to deploy OPA(open policy agent) adapter on minikube cluster (local)

Tags: adapter, istio, open-policy-agent

https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/mixer/adapter/opa
I have deployed bookinfo sample application and want to do policy enforcement through OPA.
and also set this configuration-

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: opa
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledAdapter: opa
  params:
    policy:
      - |+
        package mixerauthz
        default allow = false
    checkMethod: "data.mixerauthz.allow"
    failClose: true
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
 name: authorization
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 actions:
 - handler: opa.istio-system
   instances:
   - authzinstance.authorization
 selector: "true"
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: authzinstance
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  template: authorization
  params:
    subject:
      user: source.uid | ""
    action:
      namespace: destination.namespace | "default"
      service: destination.service | ""
      method: request.method | ""
      path: request.path | ""
EOF
```

Here, In Handler the allow is false so it should show anything to User but it doen not affect anything.(means no enforcement) Still application is showing everything just like before.

Comment: Hi, what infrastructure/platform are You using? Also which versions of Istio and minikube K8s do you have?

Comment: @PiotrMalec I am using minikube on local
 istio - 1.4.0
 minikube -v1.5.2

Comment: Can You verify if policy enforcement is enabled? Run `kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath={.data.mesh}` and look for `disablePolicyChecks:` value.

Comment: @PiotrMalec yes ,I have enabled the policy enforcement and can run simple policy like default allow=false(all request should be denyed) but when i run https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/mixer/adapter/opa/opa_integration_test.go#L100 this policy its not working

Comment: You can try to follow https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa instead of the one you linked. Its little bit more recent.